# woocommerce chained products plugin not working on multi site wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, hyperlink, woocommerce

Woocommerce chained products plugin not working on multi site wordpress. After activation links are broken. For example, I have site http://r14m2feb18.test.com/ , after activate http://ss2017beg.test.com/ .